# Ajax call NOT refreshing the DIV section during the refresh interval

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, sqljdbc

Please help. I have the following JSP file which contain an AJAX call to DIV 'alertDIV', which I require to refresh every 3 seconds.. I  want to load the jsp file 'alertbar.jsp' in every 3 seconds.. The file alertbar.jsp is used to run a query and return results..

Now, when I run the project, the calling JSP file ( 'userhome.jsp' ) is refreshing the DIV every 3 seconds.. however, when I change the value at back end, new values are not getting refreshed.. However, when I refresh the page, the changed results is getting displayed. I went through lot of suggestions and added the line '    $.ajaxSetup ({cache: false});'. Still no change... I created a simple project and used these two files alone and to my surprise, it is showing the results proper.. I have just copied the same set of code, which was working in the sample project to the existing project... but not working.. I am at my wits end on what is making the application to retain the cache ( if at all that is the reason)

I can send the code, if required.. but it is the same which was suggested in this site to refresh a DIV...

The code looks like this

### userhome. jsp

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
    });


$('#alertdiv').fadeOut('slow').load('alertbar.jsp').fadeIn("slow");
}, 3000);
</script>
```

and the

alertbar.jsp

```
<div >
    <%
        try 
        {
           %>  Alerts over  <% 
           Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1455;DatabaseName=card8","sa","adminadmin");
           Statement st=con.createStatement();
           ResultSet resultSet=st.executeQuery("select case(filetype) when 103 then 'file1' when 104 then 'file2' when 111 then 'file3' when 117 then 'file4' when 120 then 'file5' when 143 then 'file6' end , count(*)  from filecontrol where state = 101 group by filetype ");
           while(resultSet.next())
           {
            %>
            <%= resultSet.getString(1)  + ": (" + resultSet.getInt(2)+ ")   |   " %>    
            <%
           }
           %>  Alerts over  <% 
        } 
        catch( ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch( SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    %>      
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just Use Something like this in your setInterval function

```
$.ajax({    
    cache: false,
    url : urlName,
    type : 'GET',
    async: false,
    data : {},              
    success : function(data) {
        $('#alertdiv').html(data);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert('Error: ' + e); 
    }
});
```

Cheers,
vrathore.blogspot

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I tried the same, but no luck.. I was wondering whether anything has to do with different versions of jquery?